Как правильно организовать обработку входящих обновлений?
Есть телеграм клиент на tdlib, у него есть класс UpdateHandler, который реализует интерфейс ClientResultHandler и его метод, OnResult, в который приходят обновления,(UpdateNewMessage, UpdateChatPosition и так далее), все они наследуют интерфейс Update, как правильно организовать их обработку, в документации приведен пример с использованием switch case, насколько это правильно?
private class UpdateHandler : Td.ClientResultHandler
{
    void Td.ClientResultHandler.OnResult(TdApi.BaseObject @object)
    {
        if (@object is TdApi.UpdateAuthorizationState)
        {
            OnAuthorizationStateUpdated((@object as TdApi.UpdateAuthorizationState).AuthorizationState);
        }

        else if (@object is UpdateNewMessage message)
        {
            GetChatById(message.Message.ChatId);
            if (message.Message.Content is MessageText text)
                Console.WriteLine("Text: " + text.Text.Text);
        }
        else if (@object is UpdateChatPosition position)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(position.ChatId);
        }
    }
}


Где здесь switch? Этот код не работает? В чём именно вопрос?

"Правильно" у всех свое, и на этот вопрос всеж должна отвечать команда/разработчик конкретного проекта. Стандартные правила советуют делать как можно меньше вложенностей, да и разбивать все по составляющим (методам/классам), вот хотите, придерживайтесь им, это будет "правильно", лепить вот так логику разных обновлений в одном методе, это дорога к "спагетти коду". Вообще от подобных перечислений избавиться можно уймой вариантов, от простых коллекций, до таких "грязных" вещей, и опять, у каждого свое понятия "правильности" )

@EvgeniyZ вот, я пытался сформулировать вопрос о том, как уйти от "спагетти кода" и обработки всех обновлений в одном классе, просто в официальной документации как раз приведен пример, где все обрабатывается в одном классе https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/b3ab664a18f8611f4dfcd3054717504271eeaa7a/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java#L370
